# jQuery not working perfectly in Info Window of Google Map v3 with Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a info window with some click events.

But it is not working perfectly.

What I have done in jQuery to do my code is-

```
        //Set Center Button in Map ->> Click to Change Center of the Map
$(".change_center_map_button").click(function(clicked_item)
{
    clicked_item.preventDefault();
    clicked_item.stopPropagation();
        //Do what ever I want
    console.log('Set Center Button in Map Clicked');
    var latitude_this = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('lat');
    var longitude_this = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('lon');
    newMapCenter(latitude_this,longitude_this);
});
```

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: What exactly is or isn't working as expected

Comment: possible duplicate of [Info Window of Google Map v3 with Bootstrap 3 and jQuery not working perfectly in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28516905/info-window-of-google-map-v3-with-bootstrap-3-and-jquery-not-working-perfectly-i)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is because you try to set an handler on a click before the DOM is loaded. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".change_center_map_button").click(function(event) {
        var clicked_item = $(this).parent().parent().parent();

        //Do what ever I want
        console.log('Set Center Button in Map Clicked');
        var latitude = clicked_item .attr('lat');
        var longitude = clicked_item .attr('lon');
        newMapCenter(latitude, longitude);

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

If you need a live event (handling new content from ajax requests), do that instead:

```
$(document).on("click", ".change_center_map_button", function() {
    var clicked_item = $(this).parent().parent().parent();

    //Do what ever I want
    console.log('Set Center Button in Map Clicked');
    var latitude = clicked_item .attr('lat');
    var longitude = clicked_item .attr('lon');
    newMapCenter(latitude, longitude);

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

You should also take a look at "[closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)" to improve the pattern `$(this).parent().parent().parent()`.